# The separator of the last tableViewCell will not be displayed when the UITableView is added to the footerView

Tags: ios, uitableview

The separator of the last tableViewCell  will not be displayed when the UITableView is added to the footerView.How can I make it be displayed?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRs5U.png)

Comment: Please show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have no other choice than making a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and manually add the separator inside as an `UIView`.

This is rather straightforward if you're using a storyboard as you can directly design your *prototype cell* inside.